# Literature on a (partially) non linear problem

Tags: references, nonlinear-regression

I have the following model for my data vector

$d = M(\beta) \theta + n$,

where the matrix $M$ is a function of a vector of parameters $\beta$, $\theta$ is a parameter vector and $n$ is a Gaussian random vector.

It looks like a standard problem. I am interested in knowing what can be said on the parameters and which are the techniques one can use to estimate them. Can someone provide some literature on it?

I am also interested in the specific case of $M$ being block diagonal, with the same block $B(\beta)$ repeated on the diagonal.

Feel free to modify the title in order to make it more descriptive

Comment: Well, it's partially linear (if you specify $\beta$, the problem is a straight linear-in-$\theta$ problem), so the optimization can be simpler. I don't know much about algorithms for the block-diagonal structure in the nonlinear term but that should be exploitable (at the least, since the nls problem will be solved by solving a sequence of linear approximations, and solving a block-structured linear problems is fairly standard I expect this has been done before; that doesn't exploit all the structure though).